# Android калькулятор - погрешность при расчетах

Tags: android

Делаю калькулятор под Android. Минимальный API 19. Для расчетов использую double. Результат иногда оказывается не таким как можно было бы ожидать.

Например, когда делаем так **18.4 - 10.5** получаем **7.8999999...** А хотелось бы видеть **7.9**. Почему так происходит я понимаю, уже много литературы на эту тему прочитал. Но не понимаю как это обойти.

На других андроид калькуляторах, код которых нашел, та же самая проблема. Пробовал использовать BigDecimal, но программа пишет, что минимально необходимый API 24. При этом у меня на телефоне стоит предустановленный калькулятор, который каким то образом решает это и выдает правильный результат (API 21).

Подскажите как это можно решить?

Comment: [BigDecimal](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) добавлен с API level 1. Вы что-то не так делаете с ним. Или импортируете из другого пакета (android.icu.math). Вам нужен из пакета java.math.

Comment: @mit, Даже не знал, что так может быть. Android Studio автоматом делает импорт из *android.icu.math*, переделал на *java.math* все заработало.

Comment: Все решилось при использовании в расчетах BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places) нашёл функцию, которая округляет вещественные числа до заданного знака после запятой с использованием библиотеки BigDecimal:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(round(18.4 - 10.5, 6));  // 7.9
    System.out.println(round(18.43456585675467876, 6));  // 18.434566
}

public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Импортировать надо такие классы:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
```

Вот [пример](https://ideone.com/KSTesE).

Comment: зачем все эти извращения, если уже работаете с BigDecimal?

Comment: Уже? Где это "уже"? В вопросе указано, что BigDecimal как раз не используется.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, насколько понимаю, тут проблема не в округлении, а в потере остатка. Интересует только случаи с девяткой уходящей в бесконечность.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, за пример спасибо. Он меня навел на мысль )

Comment: Почему только в потере остатка? При операциях с вещественными числами результат может отличаться от реального как в большую, так и в меньшую сторону. Сложите хотя бы 0.1 и 0.2. Округление позволяет избавиться от погрешностей, т.к. они проявляются обычно достаточно далеко от запятой, т.е. до 6-8 знака можно смело округлять.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я имел ввиду, зачем эта функция? Зачем вам double в итоге? Ссылка на функцию - лишняя. Вопрос по BigDecimal решили еще в комментариях.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, добавьте в ответ весь код примера. Самой важной для решения моей проблемы оказалась вот эта часть - **round(18.4 - 10.5, 6) = 7,9**.